# Why we just use fit() method at train data in scaling problem?

Tags: scaling, feature-scaling

In feature Scaling, we just use fit() method at train data.
And not using in valid or test data.

Why we dont use mean and sd in test or valid data when we scaling test or valid data?

Comment: fit method is the training stage which is done only on the train set. Do you mean why do we scale only the train set by the mean and std?